# How do I undo a commit, and how to push only specific files?

Tags: github, push

I'm trying to push only a specific file into one of my repos, but I ended pushing all the files in the directory the file is in into my repo. For some reason, I am unable to click on some of these junk files in my github, so I cannot just click on all the useless files in question and just hit delete manually.

How do I undo my faulty push, and how do I only push that 1 specific file to my github in the future?

EDIT: ended up just deleting all the irrelevant files in my folder and committed that.

Answer (score 0):

> ended up just deleting all the irrelevant files in my folder and committed that.

That is the safest option, creating a new commit.

But if those irrelevant files were sensitive (should not have been pushed), then you could have:

```
git reset @~
git add -- only_the_relevant_files
git commit -m "right commit this time"
git push --force
```

The `--force` would have cause the previous commit pushed to GitHub to be replaced by the new one.
That can be an issue if others are using your repo. If not, that is a good way to redo that faulty commit.